# Exception when launching new project with lein new

Tags: clojure, leiningen

When I create a new project with `lein new PROJECT` and then call lein repl from within, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at clojure.main.<clinit>(main.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to call unbound fn: #'clojure.core/refer
    at clojure.lang.Var$Unbound.throwArity(Var.java:43)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.invoke(AFn.java:39)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:415)
    at clojure.lang.RT.doInit(RT.java:460)
    at clojure.lang.RT.<clinit>(RT.java:329)
    ... 1 more
Exception in thread "Thread-4" clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Subprocess failed {:exit-code 1}
    at clojure.core$ex_info.invoke(core.clj:4327)
```

Any idea what might be going on? My projects were working fine earlier in the day.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you create the project using a name with all uppercase letters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I deleted the Clojure core jar files in my maven repository (`~/.m2`). When I launched the project again Leiningen pulled down the jars and everything worked! One of the files must have got corrupted somehow :/

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a working example will help spot the problem:

```
arthur@a:~$ lein new PROJECT
Project names containing uppercase letters are not recommended 
and will be rejected by repositories like Clojars and Central. 
If you're truly unable to use a lowercase name, please set the 
LEIN_BREAK_CONVENTION environment variable and try again.

arthur@a:~$ LEIN_BREAK_CONVENTION=true lein new PROJECT
Generating a project called PROJECT based on the 'default' template.
To see other templates (app, lein plugin, etc), try `lein help new`.
arthur@a:~$ cd PROJECT/
arthur@a:~/PROJECT$ lein repl
nREPL server started on port 47462
REPL-y 0.3.0
Clojure 1.5.1
    Docs: (doc function-name-here)
          (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
  Source: (source function-name-here)
 Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
    Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)

user=> Bye for now!arthur@a:~/PROJECT$ 
arthur@a:~/PROJECT$ lein version
Leiningen 2.3.4 on Java 1.7.0_40 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
arthur@a:~/PROJECT$
```

- Are you using lein 2.3.x+? if not try lein upgrade
- Are you running lein repl in the proper directory?
- does lein deps succeed in downloading everything it needs?
- does lein version work (ie: is leiningen completely broken) if it does not work, delete ~/.lein and run it again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried updating Lein to no avail, and all my other projects were broken. Only deleting Clojure core in the maven repo resolved the issue.